# I want to transfer information from Google Docs to Google Spreadsheet

Tags: java, python, google-sheets, google-docs

I currently have a large amount of information sorted into table form on google docs, an example can be seen below:

[image]

I would like to transfer all of this information into Google Spreadsheet form. With lines 1-5 going across columns B-F, respectively, and the information going underneath each respective column.

Would I need to use a script to accomplish this task? If so, what type of script should I use, and where can I access such a script (i.e. potentially find a freelance programmer who can write it for me, if necessary). Are there any other ways this task could be accomplished? All of the information in the google docs is very standardized thus there is not any sort of variation which could complicate a script. If a script could transfer one set of 5, it could work on all of the sets.

Thank you, let me know if you need any more information.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with a lot of different languages. I would approach this using Java just because I am most familiar with it. I would start by downloading the Google Doc as plaintext (.txt). Then run it through line by line parsing it into .csv format. From there you can import it directly into Google Sheets.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with Notepad++ or equivalent editor. Need to use find and replace tool using extended keys.

Like for replacing a line break search for \r\n and replace with any you need.

If you can place \t [tab space] between fields you can simply paste them onto sheet they align into columns.

So here you can replace double line breaks with some symbol then single line break with \t and then again replace the symbol with single line break. you get all data in columns structure.